# Can the optimizer elide assignment from 64bit to 32bit integer types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given this:

```
uint64_t truncate(uint64_t num) {
    uint32_t lessBits = static_cast<uint32_t>(num);
    return static_cast<uint64_t>(lessBits);
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to optimize the static cast and keep the full 64 bit value or does it have to preserve the 32bit "truncation"?

Doing a quick [godbold check](https://godbolt.org/z/sKs6vaTdx), it would appear a `mov` [`eax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture) `, ...` is used, which means 32bit "truncation" is not optimized out.

How does the language cover this case? My current guess is this is just a case of [Integer Conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) being fully defined and the compiler observing this, so it cannot elide the assignment/32bit conversion.

Comment: I don't understand. The C++ standard prescribes observable behavior of your function, which is basically that it returns `num & 0xFFFFFFFFULL`. If the implementation would return `num` instead, it would not be standard-conforming. (BTW, note that even without truncation, the assembly would just change from `mov eax, edi` to `mov rax, rdi`. How would this be faster/more optimized?)

Comment: @DanielLangr - then your comment is a full answer. I did not claim otherwise. I *asked* because I'm not very good at the abstract language rules.

Comment: I would like to answer, however, don't have much time now. _Languag-lawyer_ tagged questions typically require elaborated answers with relevant quotations from the C++ standard, which takes some time. I will be happy if anyone possibly more experienced will write such an answer. If not, I might try to write some by myself later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the principle that optimizations must never affect defined program behavior, and the corollary that in order to allow an optimization, the Standard must characterize as Undefined Behavior all actions whose behavior it might affect, there are no defined cases where the Standard would allow implementations to make the kind of substitutions you describe.  If an implementation were to, as a form of "conforming language extension", specify that integer computations other than divide/remainder will never have any side-effects beyond yielding possibly-truncated values which may or may not be within the normal range of their types, then such an implementation with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long`, given something like:

```
long test(int *arr, int count)
{
  long total = 0;
  int subtotal = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
  {
    subtotal += arr[i];
    total += subtotal;
  }
  return total;
}
```

might at its leisure either maintain subtotal as a 32-bit `int` and sign-extend it to 64 bits on each pass of the loop before adding it to `total`, or it could sign-extend each item of `arr[i]` when it's loaded from memory and maintain a `subtotal` as a 64-bit value, and such behavioral difference may be observable in case of overflow because the implementation's "conforming language extension".

Note that there is unfortunately no way to invite compilers to perform such optimizations with types smaller than `int`, since implementations are required to document *consistent* rules for how they convert `int` and `unsigned` to smaller signed types, and would thus not be allowed to simply store smaller types in 32-bit registers without truncation and allow their whole values to be read out, even when doing so would be more efficient than truncating.

Answer (score 1):

In the C language, conversions between integer types are mandatory (except for the as-if rule, which means the compiler can do whatever it likes if it doesn't make any difference. So if every single return value of the function is ignored or assigned to a 32 bit integer, then the compiler would be allowed to not convert.)

Conversions between floating point types may be not mandatory; the compiler has some freedom to use more precision than required. However, conversion because of a cast, or conversion because of assignment to a variable, is mandatory. Also, there are pre-defined macros that allow you to detect what the compiler does.

So

```
float x = 3.1;
float y = 3.2;
double d = x * y;
double e = (float) (x * y);
float z = x * y;
```

must assign 3.1f and 3.2f to x and y. x * y can be calculated in float or double precision, so d could have different results. e and z can't. (That's because double has more than twice the mantissa bits of float, and therefore calculating x*y with infinite precision, and rounding to double first and then to float, produces the same result as rounding to float only. If long double was involved, things might be different).

Comment: "there are pre-defined macros that allow you to detect" - quick search buzzword for this?

Comment: I think this is a C answer to a C++ question, in particular the macros.